# uninstall sass gem

Tags: sass

I just upgraded to OSX lion and my sass no longer works. I keep getting this error on the watch command

ents.rb:27: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]

I read online that if you uninstall the sass gem and reinstall it it will fix the problem. I'm just not sure how to do that. Can anyone please help.

Comment: already tried a update of gem package?!

Comment: reinstall as sudo, then all sass sources will be overwritten.

Answer (score 23):

Open Terminal, and type:

```
sudo gem uninstall sass
```

Then type:

```
sudo gem install sass
```

Also if you install compass, it will install sass by default:

```
sudo gem install compass
```

To check which version you have installed, type `sass -v`

If this still doesn't solve your problem then you may want to re-install Ruby / Xcode.

Comment: Never use sudo to install gems. If you have to use sudo, you're probably using your system's ruby environment. Use RVM or chruby to install specific versions of ruby to your local user account that don't require sudo.

Answer (score 6):

Try this
to uninstall:

```
gem uninstall -Iax sass
```

& then to re-install use:

```
gem install sass --pre
```

or

```
gem install sass
```

Answer (score 1):

The general problem is that every new version of the OSX ships with a new Mac Ruby compiler. The best way to avoid those kind kinds of problems is to use [RVM](https://rvm.io/) (Ruby Version Manager) to manage your Ruby versions and avoid conflicts and missing gems (not really missing, just located in an older Ruby version).

RVM helps you keep all your gems organised and easy switching to different versions of Ruby.

For example, I use 1.9.2 version of Ruby using RVM, all my gems are located in my 1.9.2 Ruby folder. Easier to keep track, and easy to switch to newer versions of Ruby if needed.